# NULL value in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In stored procedure I have this query

```
DECLARE @BadRowsCount int;
SET @BadRowsCount = 0;

SELECT @BadRowsCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM #ImportTemp
WHERE #ImportTemp.Status <> 'A' AND #ImportTemp.Status <> 'B'
```

And `@BadRowsCount` if in `#ImportTemp.Status` are values different than A or B has positive value that is ok.

But if in `#ImportTemp.Status` is NULL `@BadRowsCount` is 0.

Why? NULL isn't different than A or B?

Status is defined as:

```
[Status] [varchar](80) NULL
```

I must define WHERE clause like:

```
WHERE (#ImportTemp.Status <> 'A' AND #ImportTemp.Status <> 'B') OR #ImportTemp.Status is NULL
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, in SQL Server, comparison operators return UNKNOWN (i.e. not true or false) if either value is a null.

MSDN [IS [NOT] NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_4) documentation

There are ways to change how SQL Server handles null comparisons with things like [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(v=sql.110).aspx).  Definitely pay attention to upcoming changes to the default for this value.

Here is an [interesting article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/) which covers several issues related to null handling.

Answer (score 1):

Because the *not equal* operator (`<>`) is, like most operators, not *NULL save*. That means it results in *unknown* when comparing with NULL.